# What are x and y in map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate?

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do some things with occupancy grids, and I cannot figure what the x and y attributes refer to. Anyone know?

Thanks,

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226960/what-are-x-and-y-in-map_msgs/occupancygridupdate?/) by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out through testing. X and Y refer to the corner of the occupancy grid update in the occupancy grid frame

---

Originally posted by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) with karma: 71 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-05-12**:
@davelkan Which corner?

**Comment by [Lucas Marins](https://answers.ros.org/users/38409/lucas-marins/) on 2019-04-11**:
@davelkan Whats is the corner? What does it mean?